# React fetch posting multiple values under same array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to post multiple values for `tag` inside an array of my fetch.

However, it is posting them connected in one array.

I would like it to always post it

## how `tag` currently sent

`tag:[{name: [null, null]}]`

## how `tag` should be sent

`tag:[
{name: "value from field"}, 
{name: "next value from field"}
]`

I also welcome suggestions on a more clean/efficient way to do this form.

here is my code:

```
class AddNew extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onTitleChange = this.onTitleChange.bind(this);
    this.onTagChange = this.onTagChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      options: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(TAG_API, {
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({ options: json });
      });
  }
  onTitleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    console.log("the title has changed" + e);
  }
  onTagChange(value) {
    this.setState({ value: value });
    console.log("they look like this" + value);
  }
  handleSubmit(e, value) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return (
      fetch(CREATE_API, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          title: this.state.itemtitle,
          tag: [
            {
              name: this.state.value.map(e => {
                e.name;
              })
            }
          ]
        })
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <textarea
            name="itemtitle"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Add new..."
            onChange={this.onTitleChange}
          />
          <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </form>
        <Select
          mode="tags"
          name="tagfield"
          onChange={this.onTagChange}
        >
          {this.state.options.map(e => (
            <Option value={e.name}> {e.name} ({e.taglevel}) </Option>
          ))}

        </Select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `handleSubmit` function, your mapping function over `this.state.value` is never returning a value (see longer explanation later). Even if it did return, you're only ever going to have an array with a single element with all the `name` values. Try changing the body composition into:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
  title: this.state.itemtitle,
  tag: this.state.value.map(e => ({ name: e.name })),
})
```

Longer explanation: Arrow functions implicitly return, unless you surround the body in curly brackets, which in that case are interpreted as a function block and you need to use explicit return. By surrounding a literal object in round brackets, you can implicitly return one.

The following two examples are equivalent:

```
const beep = () => {
   return { boop: 'bzzt' };
};

const beep = () => ({ boop: 'bzzt' });
```

Comment: Thanks for that. strangely though, that is returning empty values "tag:[{}, {}]". Ah I got it- because there is no 'name' field on 'e'. I changed `e.name` to just `e`

Comment: That's probably because you assign `e.name` to `Option`, instead of the entire object. Without knowing how `Select` and `Option` are implemented, I can only speculate.

Comment: How would I assign the entire object to it?

Comment: There are many possibilities, but the simplest example would be `<Option value={e}>`.

Comment: Yes I tried that, but it did not work. That gives me one result with all my values in it, instead of several

Comment: Also, could you show how I would send NO value where `this.state.value` is null?

Comment: @Ycon just use a ternary, or compose your request body out-of-line and use if statements.